# selecting the column with the maximum value

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in the wide format such as below:

| Subject | Volume.1 | Volume.2 | Volume.3 | Volume.4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 77 | 22 | 1 | NA |
| 2 | 65 | 182 | NA | NA |
| 3 | 98 | NA | NA | NA |
| 4 | 66 | 76 | 145 | 677 |

I am wanting to select the volume.1 and the column and the largest volume of Volume1-4 irrespective of which column it came from but am struggling to code this correctly. Some of the columns are Na when a subject does not have a recording then.

For instance with the above example the table would look like:

| Subject | Volume.1 | Worst volume |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 77 | 22 |
| 2 | 65 | 182 |
| 3 | 98 | NA |
| 4 | 66 | 677 |

I was wondering if anyone could help?

Comment: ```df$`Worst volume` = apply(df[3:5], 1, function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA else max(x, na.rm=T))```

Comment: Why is "Worst volume"  `NA` for subject 3? Your prompt states you want the largest of Volume 1-4, so why wouldn't it be 98?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `pmax`

```
cbind(df[1:2], WorseVolume = do.call(pmax, c(df[3:5], na.rm = TRUE)))
```

-output

```
 Subject Volume.1 WorseVolume
1       1       77          22
2       2       65         182
3       3       98          NA
4       4       66         677
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Subject = 1:4, Volume.1 = c(77L, 65L, 98L, 66L
), Volume.2 = c(22L, 182L, NA, 76L), Volume.3 = c(1L, NA, NA, 
145L), Volume.4 = c(NA, NA, NA, 677L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```